# htaccess redirect to https:// not fully working..?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to ensure my site always runs on `https://www.angelleye.com`.  So, both with `https://` and the `www.`  I've read some basic guides and they pretty much all show this, which is what I'm currently using.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

When I view my home page it seems to redirect me to `https://` as expected, however, if I directly load other URLs it doesn't.  For example, if I type this into my browser: `http://angelleye.com/product-category/paypal-tools/` then it does add the `www.` for me, but it leaves me on `http://` instead of moving me to `https://`.

Did I do something wrong with my htaccess rule?  Any info on how I can get this working as expected would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

**EDIT**:  I'm using WordPress with the WP Rocket caching plugin, and I just noticed that it added a bunch of rules above my rules.  Maybe there's a conflict..??  Here's a link to see the whole thing:  http://pastebin.com/fJTmbk05

**EDIT 2**: It seems to be something about my WordPress config, but I can't figure out what it would be.  If I try a URL outside my WP install it works fine.  (ie. http://angelleye.com/temp/ball.gif)

**EDIT 3**: Well, now this URL is in my WP structure but it works fine (angelleye.com/category/blog/).  So it seems that some URLs do work, but many do not..??

**EDIT 4**: I've completely removed my caching plugin, so my htaccess file now has nothing but my redirect rule.  Still works fine outside the WP structure, but not within.

Comment: It should work. Do you have more rules in your .htaccess? Is there any CMS framework in place here?

Comment: Yes.  I am using WordPress and I just noticed that my caching plugin seems to have added a bunch of rules above my rules.  I'll update the question with a link to a copy of the full contents.

Comment: Move `http->https` rule to the top and make sure to use `http://` in site and home URL in permalink settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.htaccess` file contains three sections for rewriting. The first is plugin-related, the second is WordPress-related, and the third is for your additions.

As your rules are in the third block, they won't be *seen* as the WordPress rule has already taken effect.

So, you need to move the rules you added to line 133 (above the first `mod_rewrite` definition).

The 'chain of command' or priority is now:

1. Force HTTPS and `www.`
2. WPRocket-associated rules
3. WordPress 'core' rules

Comment: Thanks!!  Moving my rules before the WP rules worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to redirect `http` to `https` forcefully with parameters.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: This isn't working for me either, but please see my update to the original question.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have the `AllowOverride` set in the `httpd.conf`?

```
RewriteEngine On
# This will enable the Rewrite capabilities

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS

RewriteRule ^/?secure/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/secure/$1 [R,L]
# This rule will redirect all users who are using any part of /secure/ to the same location but using HTTPS.
```

You would replace secure with angelleye.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me either.  The rule for adding www is working, and my home page redirects to https://, but nothing else does.